# Making connections to coin-cell batteries

Tags: pcb, batteries, design

I'm working on a project that will be using several coin cells in parallel to a flex PCB.  The product will be disposable with non-replaceable batteries, so I'm looking for ways to attach the batteries to the PCB without the cost and size of battery holders.  Putting contact pads on the PCB is usually a workable approach for rigid boards, but I'm doubting the reliability on a flex circuit.

It is possible to get metal tabs of the appropriate size spot-welded to the cells so that they can be soldered, which may be the best route.  Are there any others I should consider to make reliable connections?  Conductive epoxy?

Comment: Digikey Product Index > Battery Products > Batteries Non-Rechargeable (Primary) > Termination Style: SMD (SMT) Tab

Answer (score 1):

I have outsourced to battery manufacturers that provided shrink wrapped lithium batteries packs that relied on the wrap to make connections between batteries.  They then mechanically connected tabs onto the cells which I could then solder leads onto.

Soldering coin cells at least causes damage that will lower the operating length of your device and at worst will cause thermal runaway and can be very dangerous.